# Initialize a list of objects with string input and list comprehensions - input().split() results in Value Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use list comprehensions to read four lines of input and convert the lines into a list of objects.

Here's my code:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
        
    def __str__(self):
        return "[Person = {} {} {}]".format(self.x, self.y, self.z)


def main():
    n = int(input())
    
    li = [[Person(int(x), int(y), int(z)) for x, y, z in input().split()][0] for i in range(n)]
    
    for p in li:
        print(str(p))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here's my input:

```
4
34 45 56
12 23 34
23 355 66666
87 67 45
```

But the code is not successful. The error depends on the editor, but my most recent error is:
`li = [[Person(int(x), int(y), int(z)) for x, y, z in input().split()][0] for i in range(n)]         ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack`

I believe it's the pesky `input().split()` that's causing issues.

Comment: `li = [Person(int(x), int(y), int(z)) for x, y, z in [input().split() for i in range(n)]]` works though, but i don't want to read in all the input first.

Comment: The problem with your code is that `input().split()` is not something to iterate over; it's the single value you want to unpack. It is iterable (since you can unpack it), but it means you are then trying to unpack `34` into `x`, `y` and `z` variables before you try to unpack `45` the same way.

Comment: Moral of the story: trying to cram too much code into one line makes it difficult to spot these kinds of errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try to keep your input handling separate from your business logic.

```
def main():
    # Phase 1: input and validation
    try:
        line = input()
    except Exception:
        sys.exit("Problem reading record count from input")

    try:
        n = int(line)
    except ValueError:
        sys.exit(f"Problem parsing record count {line}")

    
    parameters = []

    for i in range(1, n+1):
        try:
            line = input()
        except Exception:
            sys.exit(f"Problem reading record {i} from input")

        try:
            x, y, z = map(int, line.strip().split())
        except Exception:
            sys.exit(f"Problem parsing record {i}: {line}")

        parameters.append((x, y, z))

    # Phase 2: Business logic
    li = [Person(*t) for t in parameters]  # or Person(x, y, z) for x, y, z in parameters]

    for p in li:
        print(str(p))
```

You can do as little or as much input validation as you like during the first phase. Assuming you haven't encountered any errors leading to program exit, you can safely create your list of `Person` objects.

Answer (score 0):

By using `input().split()` you're creating a list with 3 elements, one for each word in the string. If you want to achieve the wanted unpacking you need to separate the loop from the unpacking with another function for your external loop, like this one:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "[Person = {} {} {}]".format(self.x, self.y, self.z)

def unpackSplit():
    x,y,z = input().split()
    return Person(int(x), int(y), int(z)) 

def main():
    n = int(input())

    li = [unpackSplit() for i in range(n)]

    for p in li:
        print(str(p))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Thank you @wwii! I've missed the class indentation. Now it should be all fixed.